# AngularJS Mean.js Atom Beautifier Javascript Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean, atom-editor

I've just spent the last many hours debugging a problem that occurs after atom beautification.  My question regards why would the following be an issue.

This is a snippet of code in the MEAN.js scaffolding in the file layout.server.view.html:  (I dont know what this code does... but that's a different story)

```
<!--Embedding The User Object-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var user = {{ user | json | safe }};
  </script>
```

After I use the atom beautifier it looks like this:

```
<!--Embedding The User Object-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var user = {
    {
        user | json | safe
    }
  };
</script>
```

The latter causes a javascript error in chrome and firefox.

And my question is... why.  I did not think white space mattered in javascript.  I'd also like to know what this code is doing, if you have a few more cycles.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually bit me once before and I STILL was stumped by it when it bit me again just now.

Two curly brackets ({{...}}) tells AngularJS to evaluate the contents as an expression. Beautifier breaks this by helpfully breaking up the doubled curly brackets into separate lines. Because that's what you meant to do, right?